# struggling with Object Oriented class design

Tags: c++, oop

I'm comming from an scientific background and I'm having trouble to think object oriented. I'm always thinking of functions not objects.

For example I've got a Dataset containing multiple 2D arrays and I like to extract Regions of Interest out of these arrays. So my first Design was something like a RoIFinder class to whom I pass a reference to the Dataset object. The RoIFinder object did its magic and returned the RoI's.

But this gives me a bad feeling since it looks more like a function than an object.It's more like a Blackbox. But I have no Idea how it is done properly.

How would you do something like that?

Comment: Why would you want to work with matrices in C++? MATLAB and Octave seem like much better tools for that.

Comment: I'm actually working with the Eigen Library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it sounds like in the specific situation you describe, this could be a fine OO design.

OO in brief is about bundling together

- state
- behaviour
- (identity).

Whenever you have data which represents the state of (a part of) the system, and you have behaviour tied to (typically manipulating) that data, you have a candidate for an object. Optionally, these objects may also have an identity, but this may not be always necessary.

If you potentially have multiple different criteria to pick regions of interests out of the Dataset, you may implement these as distinct `*Finder` classes, implementing a common base interface. There you have an OO class hierarchy! From then on, the Finders can even be used as interchangeable [Strategies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) in your code.

The alternative would be to put the finder functionality in the Dataset. This *might* be OK if you are absolutely sure you won't have more different criteria to extract regions. Even then, your Dataset has two distinct responsibilities, which is usually not a good idea. It is better to have each class be responsible for one thing, and do it well.

We don't know what you are supposed to do with the data in the arrays - there may be some possibility to find more abstractions there and build some OO types and objects on these too.

Note though, that these all are just possibilities. Implement them only if they are actually useful (for solving problems, simplifying your code, or - last but not least - helping you gain practical experience with new concepts).

Answer (score 4):

OO is not a silver bullet. Do your work in whichever way it seems to be correct from the different points of view: problem decomposition, efficiency, code simplicity, testing, etc.

Do not make the code look in OO way if you don't need to. The OO is about simplification the life when the problem is too complex, not for making simple problems solved in a complicated way.

Specifically for your problem, I see nothing bad in your approach. It possibly doesn't use some advanced techniques, so what?

Comment: It's worth emphasising that C++ is explicitly a multiparadigm language, unlike some languages such as Smalltalk or Java that are designed specifically to support one paradigm. If you were writing in Smalltalk you'd need a much better reason to write in a non-OO style.

Answer (score 0):

What you've done is probably better than the obvious OO approach of adding a `find_roi()` to the Dataset class itself.  Why?  Because it sounds like you've created the RoIFinder functionality based only on the public API of Dataset.  Keeping Dataset simpler is also good.  The STL (well these days it's just part of the Standard library) has examples of this in the way algorithms such as sort are applicable to multiple containers, rather than each container have a sort member function (although in the case of list optimisation opportunities leads it to implementing its own version).  The STL also has std::string which controvertially embeds a lot of functionality that could have been factored out - in my opinion it is well designed, prioritorising convenient and elegant usage which is important in such a ubiquitous class which is so frequently and heavily operated on.  So, pick what suits the situation.  Anyway, there's no reason to put the RoIFinder into a class if it could equally be just a function, but if you've found some state (i.e. data members) that are convenient to preserve, or it helps usability in some other way, then that's a good enough reason to stick with your object.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2D array can be implemented as a matrix class. One object
A region of interest is another class.

Getting a region of interest out of a matrix is a method.

"Iterators" into your matrices are classes.